# AIR -connecting to more than 1 arduino

Tags: actionscript-3, air, arduino

I am using the arduinconnector ANE to connect to an arduino baord in an AIR application. 
https://code.google.com/p/as3-arduino-connector/

Can anyone tell me if its possible to connect to more than 1 board, simply by instantiating additional instances of the ANE and passing in unique port #'s?

Or is there some reason why this isn't possible and a unique AIR application is required for every arduino you connect to?

Comment: Did you know there is now an arduino specific  stack exchange (http://arduino.stackexchange.com/). It might be worth asking there.